# PHP - Como enviar información de mis inputs a pantalla en tiempo real

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un simple formulario donde tengo 2 inputs uno para el nombre y el otro para el apellido, me gustaría saber como enviar esta información para que apareciera en pantalla en tiempo real, saludos y gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor trata de poner lo que has intentado y explicar mejor lo que quieres si es preciso con ejrmplos,se presta para confusion tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con php puro no puedes hacer eso ya que es un lenguaje del lado del servidor y no manipula el DOM, con javascript si se puede hacer, ahora si lo que deseas es mostrar y al mismo tiempo guardar la información en una base de datos, lo que debes de usar es Ajax:

Aquí un pequeño ejemplo sin usar php (no guardar en base de datos):

```js
//PARA ESTE EJEMPLO USAREMOS JQUERY UNA LIBRERIA DE JAVASCRIPT

$(document).on("keyup", "#formulario input[name='nombre'], #formulario input[name='apellido']", function(event){
     let nombre=''
     let apellido=''
    if(event.target.name=="nombre")
    {
   
        nombre = this.value   
       $("#nombre").text(nombre)

    }else if(event.target.name=="apellido")
    {
       apellido = this.value
       $("#apellido").text(apellido)
    }
    
    

})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form method="POST" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder='Ingrese su nombre'>    
    <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder='Ingrese su Apellido'>
</form>


<div id="mostrarDatos">
<h5>Resultado</h5>
      <p id="nombre"></p>     
      <p id="apellido"></p>


</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Arellano, me ayudaste mucho es lo que buscaba realizar, una disculpa tratare de formular mejor mis preguntas es mi primera vez como usuario en la pagina, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que pude entender solo quieres mostrar en pantalla los datos que metes por medio del formulario. Si esto es así, lo puedes hacer con javascript y un par de `<div>` por medio de su ID.

Aquí te dejo el código, que lo unico que hace el pasarle los parámetros a una función "datos" y esta los asigna a los divs del html.

Prueba y nos dices si eso es lo que buscas.

```
<script>
function datos(nombre,apellido){
    document.getElementById('minombre').innerHTML=nombre;
    document.getElementById('miapellido').innerHTML=apellido;
    }
</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" /> 
    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" />
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Mostrar en pantalla" onclick="datos(nombre.value,apellido.value);"/>
</form>

<div id="minombre"></div>
<div id="miapellido"></div>
```